# Проблема с запуском prometheus в gitlab

Tags: debian, gitlab, prometheus

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. На серваке дебиан крутится гитлаб, в один прекрасный момент появляется 500 ошибка. Захожу на сервер и вижу такую ситуацию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`

Прометеус лежит себе и не шевелится, перезагрузил гитлаб и сам прометеус, не помогло. Открываю лог и вижу такое[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пустой json блокирует директорию, удаляю ее. Перезагружаю опять все, прометеус запустился, а вот при запуске гитлаба пишет что он запустился, но сразу выключился. Хотя сама служба работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге gitlab так и не завелся, так же прилагаю скриншот памяти, может в этом проблема и если да, то подскажите что вычистить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Перемести или удали не нужные логи и данные прометея,
как gitlab запуститься почисти image
у тебя все на 1 разделе, в дальшейнем разнеси gitaly, postgres, images, prometheus на разные разделы